# Pegar evento click dentro de iframe com jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, cookies

Estou usando o *Google Forms* para fazer uma pesquisa de satisfação em um site. Nesse site eu mostro uma barra no topo, pedindo ao usuário que participe. Se ele fechar a mensagem, é gravado um cookie que expira em 24 horas para que não veja mais a mensagem naquele dia.

Eu gostaria de gravar um cookie, caso o usuário responda o questionário para que ele não veja mais a mensagem no site.

Alguém sabe de um jeito de fazer isso?

> **Edição:**
>   Consigo gravar o cookie com jQuery.
>   Existe alguma forma de pegar o evento click do form? Via javascript ou jquery.
>   Ele está em um iframe e não consigo usar jquery, por exemplo, e pegar o evento click.

**Iframe:**

```
<iframe src="endereco_do_form" width="955" height="700" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Carregando...</iframe>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
    $('#ss-submit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("OK")
    });
</script>
```

Comment: #ss-submit é o id do button. Peguei pelo devtools.

Comment: Vi que não posso pegar o evento por causa das políticas da mesma origem. Alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você não pode interagir com o conteúdo de um iframe vindo de outro domínio que não seja o do seu site. Mas você pode criar um botão FECHAR fora do iframe e assim gravar o cookie válido por 24h. No caso do usuário responder à pesquisa, você precisa de um callback do Google com o ID da pesquisa que será enviado ao seu site de forma que vc identifique isso e grave um cookie com validade "ilimitada" para que a pesquisa não apareça mais praquele usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Para ver o conteúdo deste iframe faz isso:
var frame = window.frames[0].document;
O .frames[0] -> 0 representa o único iframe na tela, caso exista outro é necessário colocar qual index do iframe.